# How can I create a double loop and populate it with numbers?

Tags: r

I created a 4✕5 matrix and use a double loop to populate it with numbers so that the value of an element in the matrix is its row index raised to the power of its column index (e.g. the value of the element in row 2 and column 3 is 2 raised to the power of 3, i.e. 8).

How can I create a double loop and populate it with numbers?

Comment: *"I created a 4x5 matrix and use a double loop"* ... and then you ask *"how can I create a double loop and populate it with numbers"*. Which is it: you created it, or you didn't create it. You shouldn't need loops, though: `outer(1:4, 1:5, \`^\`)` works.

Comment: I think the question was edited to make it sound less like homework :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use outer.

```
outer(1:4, 1:5, "^")
```

Answer (score -1):

This is just a common way of writing it. I'd appreciate if you upvote/accept answer if it solves your problem.

```
M = matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
for (i in seq(nrow(M))){
  for (j in seq(ncol(M))){
    M[i,j] = i^j
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it, thank you very much Hong for breaking it down for me

Comment: You are very welcome. Dason has a more concise solution but this one is like the very basic way to do it :)

Comment: Great. It is so comprehensive